# Clojure def vs defn for a function with no arguments

Tags: clojure

I have written a program in clojure but some of the functions have no arguments. What would be the advantages of coding such functions as a "def" instead of a "defn" with no arguments?

Comment: Do you mean `(def x (fn [] (something)))`, or `(def x (something))`? They're completely different, and the accepted answer is only correct for the second interpretation.

Comment: I guess the second interpration, but good point!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`def`s are evaluated only once whereas `defn`s (with or without arguments) are evaluated (executed) every time they are called. So if your functions always return the same value, you can change them to `def`s but not otherwise.

Comment: Ah, I did not know this, you saved me from some serious bugs! So if there is a def which accesses a reference it will never be recalculated? What about if the file is reloaded?

Comment: `def` is reevaluated when the file is reloaded.

Comment: It seems wrong to me to say that `defn` forms are reevaluated. As pointed out in other answers, `defn` resolves to `def` at macro expanding time, and they indeed are all evaluated only once at file load time.

Comment: @MattFenwick skuro's point is that `defn`s are evaluated only once, just like every `def` - in this case, it defines a function. However, the *body* of the function defined may be evaluated any number of times. I don't think it's a useful distinction, but he's not saying anything false.

Comment: I read the question as `(def x (fn [] (do-something-here)))`, whereas you seem to be interpreting it as `(defn x [] (do-something-here)`. It'd be nice if the OP were specific enough to know which interpretation is correct.

Comment: Charles makes an important distinction, but the original poster is only one consumer of this information here.  Given the potential for confusion I don't think this is an effective accepted answer in its current form. Siefca's answer below addresses this potential confusion specifically.

Answer (score 131):

```
(def t0 (System/currentTimeMillis))
(defn t1 [] (System/currentTimeMillis))
(t1)
;; => 1318408717941
t0
;; => 1318408644243
t0
;; => 1318408644243
(t1)
;; => 1318408719361
```

Comment: thanks. this code example was worth more than a 1000 word description.

Comment: So that no one misses this crucial point: As Roman Bataev's comment implies, `(def t2 (fn [] (System/currentTimeMillis)))` will make `t2` behave like `t1`.

Comment: `def` binds a value to a name, `defn` defines a function and binds it to a name. More details at [defn vs fn](https://clojure.org/guides/learn/functions#__code_defn_code_vs_code_fn_code)

Answer (score 50):

(defn name ...) is just a macro that turns into (def name (fn ...) anyway, not matter how many parameters it has. So it's just a shortcut. See (doc defn) for details.

https://clojure.org/guides/learn/functions#_defn_vs_fn

Comment: This is the most concise answer out there! If anyone Googles "defn vs def", I hope he will quickly get to this thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

The `def` special form creates a **Var** object identified by a symbol given as its first argument. Identification is created by associating the given symbol with a Var in a map called namespace.

The Var holds **a reference to some value**, which could be expressed (among others):

- as a constant form, which **always evaluates to its own value**:

```clj
(def x 1)
x
;; => 1             ; x holds a reference to a number 1
```

- as a function form, which at first **is evaluated to its resulting value**:

```clj
(def x (+ 2 2))
x
;; => 4             ; x holds a reference to a number 4
```

- as a Java method form, which at first **is evaluated to its resulting value**:

```clj
(def x (System/currentTimeMillis))
x
;; => 1417811438904 ; x holds a reference to a number 1417811438904
x
;; => 1417811438904 ; still the same number!
```

- as a lambda form (anonymous function), which at first **is evaluated to a function object**:

```clj
(def x (fn [] (System/currentTimeMillis)))
x
;; => #<user$x user$x@4c2b1826>
(x)                             ; function form, function evaluated
;; => 1417811438904
(x)                             ; function form, function evaluated
;; => 1417812565866
```

There is a simple rule for all of the above. In case of `def` special form an S-expression given as its second argument is **recursively evaluated** **before binding is created**, so the resulting Var is bound to the result of this evaluation.

Even `fn` is evaluated before, but its resulting value is a function object that holds a code. This code will be executed (and evaluated) **each time the function is called**. That's why there are different results.

The `defn` macro is just like `def` but internally it creates an anonymous function and then binds a Var object to it. Its second argument becomes a body of this function and it's not evaluated in a "regular" way. One could also say it is evaluated but as a lambda form – the result of the evaluation is a function object, not the result of some instant calculation.

So writing:

```
(defn fun [] 1)
```

Is synonymous to:

```
(def fun (fn [] 1))
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Should be the accepted answer.